# I can't click on an app icon in Launcher Dash in 16.04, how to fix?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash

I just upgraded to 16.04 last week and moved the launcher down. Since then, the app icons in the Launcher Dash are un-clickable. When i try to click, my click does not go to the launcher dash, but instead goes to the window in the background. That means i always have to use my arrow keys to navigate, and that gets kinda annoying because

- i can't drag an app from the Launcher Dash and pin it to the Launcher.
- i need to press my arrow keys many times to get to a result all the way at the bottom
- and sometime i make a mistake and open a window i didn't mean to.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Oh, I have a similar problem! I can open Dash but can't click on app icons. Also my auto-hiding sidebar doesn't reveal on mouse-over (but I still can see it if I'll turn off auto-hide). And when I use Alt+Tab, it changes active window but I don't see 'apps selector' as usual. 

Does rebooting system help you? It works for me. Today I've find method to restart Unity without closing my apps, it may be interesting for you: `unity --replace &` (in Terminal)

Comment: I have the exact same issue on Ubuntu 17.04. Running `unity --replace` seems to crash compiz and freeze the screen. Rebooting doesn't help

Comment: To pin something to the launcher, you can still right-click on it after opening it and say "Lock to launcher"

Comment: Same problem here, but it only happens on my laptop display when a 2nd monitor is connected.

Answer (score 11):

Try to reload gnome screen by pressing ALT + F2.
Then type "r" into the input field and press ENTER.

Comment: Not relevant for a user who is asking about the Unity desktop.

Comment: That really worked here, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 here. Just tried this and it worked. I had to alt tab to the program to interact with it and the app bar was un-clickable. I was about to restart my computer. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just typed "Unity" in a terminal and it seemed to fix the issue.